# com.facebook.react.bridge.readablenativemap cannot be cast to java.lang.string

Tags: react-native, fetch, multipartform-data

My code:

```
const file = {
  uri: this.state.imageSource,
  name: this.state.imageName,
  type: 'image/jpg',
};

const data = new FormData();
data.append('file', file);

fetch(config.server + '/upload', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: data,
})
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((responseData) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(responseData));
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    alert(err);
  });
```

Without **FormData** code doesnt display error. What I should do to fix? Debugging on android.

Comment: looks like fetch only works with strings, or `JSON.stringify`'ied data , not with `FormData`

Comment: without JSON.stringify, error does not disappear.

Comment: were you able to find a solution to this problem ?

Comment: I had a similar thing just now where I was passing an object to Alert.alert(). I hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The error was because I was passing in the url as an array but it expected a string.

Comment: Got the same error when passing an object where a string was required. Can be stringified with `JSON.stringify(theobject)`. May not be appropriate in this case of an array of URLs though.

Answer (score 4):

This will resolve the issue :
`alert(JSON.stringify(data))`

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error because my URL was incorrect

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was not running the api server.

Answer (score 0):

In case this is helpful to someone, I was getting this error:

`com.facebook.react.bridge.readableNativeArray cannot be cast to java.lang.boolean`

And the issue was me passing a string instead of a boolean to a component.

Answer (score -1):

I also faced the same issue and the below line of code can be a solution.

```
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("mobile", phonenumber);

var requestOptions = {
method: 'POST',
body: formdata,
redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("http://your_url", requestOptions)
.then(response => response.text())
.then(result => console.log(result))
.catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Answer (score -2):

```
react-native link
```

Use this command to resolve this issue. This worked for me.

Note :  Only for react-native < 60.x